# jQuery draggable on computer and touch screens

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

I have the script below and it works amazingly for the needs of what i am doing, is there any method that would allow me to use this script so that it can be used on both a machine using a mouse as well as a a touch screen tablet or ipads/iphone or mobiles, any idea how this can be achieved.

```
 $(function () {

    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({containment: "#content1" });

    $('.ui-widget-header').each(function (i, ele) {

        // Gets the accepted from the HTML property "data-accept"
        var accept = $(this).data('accept');

        // This is just to show what the item accepts. you can remove it.
        $(this).find('p').text('accepts: ' + accept);

        // Init the jQuery UI droppable()
        $(this).droppable({
            accept: accept,
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this)
                    .removeClass("ui-widget-header")
                    .addClass("correct")
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass("correct").addClass("ui-widget-header")

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should check this out: **https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch**

Comment: this stops is working full stop